# How to dynamically add part of an object with an arg in a vue method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Super simple question but i've never been able to solve it.
Say we have some data:

```
section: {
  option1: true,
  option2: true
}
```

and on a button we have:

```
<button @click="toggle(option1)">
```

How do I dynamically paste 'option1' arg into something like this:

```
toggle(opp){
console.log(this.section.opp)
}
```

Because currently it's literally looking for this.section.opp, and opp doesn't exist in the data.

Comment: `toggle('option1')` and `console.log(this.section[opp])` - just as it always is in javascript :p

Comment: Legend. Sometimes I just have a brain fart hey.

Comment: @JackSumner I added an answer. Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.section[opp]` instead of `this.section.opp` as opp contains dynamic value and can not access directly with dot(.) notation as it is containing a different value.

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    section: {
      option1: true,
      option2: true
    },
    result: null
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(opp) {
      this.result = this.section[opp];
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggle('option1')">Click Me</button>
  <p>Result: {{ result }}</p>
</div>
```